# Update and Remove shared dll

Tags: installation, components, guid

I have product abc which has a.dll version 1 in product xyz needs to update a.dll to version 2 and add other dlls to the system. When i uninstall product xyz i need a.dll to be downgraded back to version 1.

I need two different installers for product abc and product xyz patch is not a option.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with some backup and restore custom actions, but it's not an easy task. You would also have to code most of the backup and restore mechanism.

There is also a design problem. If product *abc* is designed to work with version 1 and you overwrite it with version 2, product *abc* could no longer work.

My advice is to let each product use it's own DLLs.

If you really want to share the DLL, you can make sure that its component has the same name and GUID in all products. In this case the first DLL (version 1) will be shared by all products and it will never be overwritten by another version.

Comment: To extend further, thanks for your quick reply. A.dll relies on b.dll in product abc. When product xyz updates A.dll it relies on c.dll, d.dll and e.dll. b.dll remains on the system however when xyz is uninstalled and a.dll is downgraded to a.dll version 1 it would just work because b.dll remains. When product abc is installed it changes a config file which refers to a.dll name and we dont want to change the config file when we install product xyz.